# Centering multiple objects adjacent to each other with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have multiple canvases that I want to display adjacent to each other. I'm not the most familiar with CSS but I've tried placing them all in a div that is centered, with each under a specific float (canvas_left set to float left, canvas_center set to canvas center, or canvas_right set to float right). For some reason I can't get them all be to adjacent and centered horizontally on the screen.

CSS:

```
.left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <canvas id="canvas_left" class="left" width="150px" height="400px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_main" class="center"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_right" class="right" width="150px" height="400px"></canvas>
</div>
```

If you know how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using flexboxes, you can do almost anything with that.

Also the container class is the same as the child one, you should change that, like so:

```
<div id="canvas">
  <canvas id="canvas_left" class="left" width="150px" height="400px"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_main" class="center"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_right" class="right" width="150px" height="400px"></canvas>
</div>


#canvas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left { background: green; flex-shrink: 0; }
.center { background: blue; flex-shrink: 0; }
.right { background: purple; flex-shrink: 0; }
```

JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/8uv2zowm](https://jsfiddle.net/8uv2zowm/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no float center. You layout doesn't work because the main canvas is a non-floated block.

Using floats is probably a bad idea anyways. Better use inline-blocks:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas_left"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_main"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_right"></canvas>
</div>
```

Or flexbox, the modern way to do it:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas_left"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_main"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_right"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float all `canvas` tags. Change your CSS:

```
.left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

But be aware that when changing display width, the canvas tags will again be aligned under each other.

Play around [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/1y0zvjw4/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve.

CSS

```
.container {
  float: left;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas_left" class="left"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_main" class="center"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_right" class="right"></canvas>
</div>
```